# How do I call the @using (Html.BeginForm()) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, timer

<--THIS IS THE TIMER I WANT -->  UPDATED
Trying to get the timer to automatically hit the submit button and go to next page.         There is a controller that scores the quiz so I need to use the @using htmlBeginForm used     below. TIMER

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-1">
    <section id="questionForm">
        <h2>Questions</h2>

        <form name="counter">
            <input type="text" size="8"
                   name="d2">
        </form>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var minutes = 1
            var seconds = 00

            document.counter.d2.value = '30:00'

            function display()
            {
                if (seconds <= 0)
                {
                    minutes -= 1
                    seconds += 59
                }
                if (minutes <= -1)
                {

                    function nextQuestion() {
                        $("#questionform").trigger("submit");
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        setTimeout(function () { nextQuestion() }, 5000);
                    });

                }
                else
                    seconds -= 1
                document.counter.d2.value = minutes + ":" + seconds
                setTimeout("display()", 1000)
            }
            display()
        </script>





        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Questions", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "questionform" }))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Questions)

            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
        }
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to submit the form after a given time. For this you can use just the `setTimeout` function.

`@using htmlBeginForm` is the Razor syntax for creating `form` tag and at the end you will have the same old `form` tag in your rendered `View`. You can use below code to give your own ID.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "questionform" }))
```

Since you have added `jQuery` tag, I assume you can use `jQuery` and try following JavaScript code.

I assume your layout page has jQuery and `script` section as below.

```
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Then your view should be like below.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1">
    <section id="questionForm">
        <h2>Questions</h2>

        <div id='countdown'></div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Questions", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "questionform" }))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Questions)
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
        }
    </section>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            countdown('countdown');
        });

        function countdown(element) {
            var interval;
            var minutes = 1;
            var seconds = 30;

            interval = setInterval(function() {
                var el = document.getElementById(element);
                if(seconds == 0) {
                    if(minutes == 0) {
                        el.innerHTML = "Time's Up!";                    
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        $("#questionform").trigger("submit");
                        return;
                    } else {
                        minutes--;
                        seconds = 60;
                    }
                }
                el.innerHTML = minutes + ' : ' + seconds;
                seconds--;
            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3TFnc/6/)

Comment: If I implement this code, then I am not getting a timer that shows on the page.

Comment: do you know why? Is it because it isn't in a form?

Comment: Did you try exactly what I have mentioned in the answer ? Please check with the JSFiddle Example.

Comment: That does work but it is not necessarily what I need.  I have to use the
(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Questions", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "questionform" }))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Questions)
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
        }

I have to use this because it goes to a location that will score the quiz

Comment: Yes, you can keep that in your view, isn't it working with `Html.BeginForm` as I mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: It's not. The JSFiddle Example gives the "action" as /questions/index.  In the @html.beginform, I am giving it /questions/index but the questsions here is a controller, not a view.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, on submit your data will be posted to `questions` controller's `index` method. In that `index` method you can return the next view. Is that what you want to do ?

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I want to do.  But the way you set it up, it had a form tag and then the javascript underneath, right? That didn't work

Comment: Yes, that's because in JSFiddle I cannot write Razor syntax. Try the code in the answer and set your `index` method accordingly. Let me know if you get any issues.

Comment: I tried it but I wasn't getting a timer showing up with what you have in the answer

Comment: Where did you add the jQuery reference ? If it is is linked in the script section at the bottom of the layout page, you have to move this JavaScript code to script section.

Comment: I have it so that everything you have in the js fiddle, not including the data in between the form tags, is in between script tags.  I should need anything else because my form is below, using @html.beginform

Comment: I have it in my code as I basically posted first, the very first picture on this page with my code.  I just put all of your javascript in between the script tags instead of what I had.

Comment: Is there any way you can post code on this page with my code that will give a working timer.  My whole view page is posted above

Comment: Can you post your `_Layout.cshtml` page ? Then I can tell you how you can put this JavaScript correctly.

Comment: The _Layout.cshtml is not where I want the timer though, I need it in the questions view with is the index.cshtml page I have above.  It is the very first set of code at the top of the page.  Can you embed it in that code? Also, do I need to reference on the cshtml page that I am using jquery anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I understand. I want to see the `_Layout.cshtml` to check how you have linked the jQuery. If it is in the bottom of the layout page, then you have to put that script in the `scripts` section. Check the updated answer.

Comment: So the code is functional but it doesn't go to another page after the timer

Comment: And just to confirm, on my layout page I have :

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Comment: Can you see the `Time's Up!` message?

Comment: Actually, I ended up figuring out another way to do it.  Sorry if this is a little random, but can you help me with one other minor issue I am having.  It deals with a submit resume function.  I just want to notify the user if the file they submit is too big rather than the page ridirecting to a "Maximum request length exceeded page" 

Here is the link I have posted with code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073251/how-to-let-user-know-the-resume-they-are-submitting-is-too-large/25073420?noredirect=1#comment39220120_25073420