# How to let user know the resume they are submitting is too large

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

my cshtml file for upload, where would the javacsript go in this file?

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

<div id="progressbar">
<div id="progressbar" class="all-rounded" style="width: 20%"><span></span></div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">

<h2>Job Application Management System</h2>
<p class="lead2"> Welcome @((string)(ViewData["FullName"])), Please upload your resume here. Thank  you!</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =     "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <label> &nbsp; </label> <input type="file" class="btn btn-default"   name="File"     id="File" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="upload" value="Upload" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
if (TempData["notice"] != null)
{
    <p>@TempData["notice"]</p>
    <p><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Accomplishments")';return false;">Continue To Accomplishments</button></p>
}
}
```

Here is my working code that shows how to accept a resume and save it using asp.net mvc
How do I post an error message stating that the file size is too large if the user submits a file that cannot be handled.  Right now, if a user submits a file too large, it takes them to an errors page.  I just want a popup or something on the screen that tells them to submit a file that is smaller. Thanks!

```
            if (resume.File.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(resume.File.FileName);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Resumes"), fileName);
                resume.File.SaveAs(path);
            }
            TempData["notice"] = "Resume Added:  "+ resume.File.FileName;
            return View(resume);


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Upload Error";
            return View("Upload");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple javascript :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#image-file').on('change', function() {
   var filesize = this.files[0].size/1024/1024).toFixed(2) + " MB");
   //Now can use use filesize variable and check it's value and show pop.
  });
</script>
```

OR you can use this :

```
function GetFileSize(fileid) {
try {
    var fileSize = 0;
    //for IE
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        //before making an object of ActiveXObject, 
        //please make sure ActiveX is enabled in your IE browser
        var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); var filePath = $("#" + fileid)[0].value;
        var objFile = objFSO.getFile(filePath);
        var fileSize = objFile.size; //size in kb
        fileSize = fileSize / 1048576; //size in mb 
    }
        //for FF, Safari, Opeara and Others
    else {
        fileSize = $("#" + fileid)[0].files[0].size //It will calculate file size in kb

         // Put Your Alert or Validation Message Here


    }

}
catch (e) {
    alert("Error is :" + e);
}
}
```

Or you can check file size on form submit as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#upload').on('click', function(e) {
   e.PreventDefault();
   var filesize = $("#File").files[0].size/1024/1024).toFixed(2));  //filesie in MB
   //Now can use use filesize variable and check it's value and show pop.
    if(parseInt(filesize)>3){ alert("File too large");return false; }
    else{ $("form").submit(); }
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying this code and it is not working properly.  Is there a way to just write to the screen, doesn't have to be a pop up window, that says the file is too large.  I was thinking that it would just be an "if" statement where I say that if the file is bigger than an amount, tell them to resubmit and upload again

Comment: what is the id of your file upload??

Comment: id? It just takes a file and saves it to a folder

Comment: I have uploaded my cshtml file, can you help me go from there?

Comment: @user3889538....just try my 3rd answer it will work...just make sure to include jquery file also....

Comment: how can I ensure I have that jquery file?

Comment: in scripts or check it in contents folder there is jquery file just drag and drop it at the top of your view.

Comment: My content folder only contains my bootstrap css stuff

Comment: In my scripts folder, I have several jquery files

Comment: jquery-1.10.1.js..just give its reference at the top in your view

Comment: in the script tag, how should it look?

Comment: just use same thing as my 3rd answer...@user3889538

Comment: Is the #upload you use in the 3rd answer taken from my code where I set ID="upload".  Also, if I am using this jquery process, in my script tag or my view cshtml page, do I need to specify I am using jquery 1.10.1.js anywhere?

Comment: just add jquery 1.10.1 reference at the top of your view... @user3889538

Comment: I did that but now it just shows on the webpage. Where exactly does it go?

Comment: @user3889538...i think your problem is solved if submitting document is more than desired size limit then form will not submit otherwise form will be submitted...

Comment: I meant I put jquery 1.10.1 at the top of the view cshtml page and now jquery 1.10.1 is showing as text on the page.  I just want to implement the javascript so that I have a file size limit.  If I submit a file that is 22MB for example, I still get thrown to a page that says "Maximum request length, etc".  I would just want the screen or a popup box to say the file size is too large and you must resubmit.

Comment: What is the correct syntax to add jquery 1.10.1 at the top of the view? Or should it be in the script tag?

Comment: Hey I am getting a syntax error when I use that javascript code. There are some errors within it. Can you please check please? I can't figure it out

Comment: @user3889538....there is nothing wrong with my code.. there will be some problems with way you are using Javascript. . .just post a question on stackoverflow without seeing your complete code i cant figure out your problem.... thankzzz....